# Continuous Random Variable: Distribution Function & Expected Value

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Given

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x < 1 \\
c(x-1)^2, & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
1, & x \geq 2
\end{cases} $$

1. Find the values of $c$ for which $F(x)$ is the distribution function of a random variable $X$.
2. Establish for what value of $c$ the random variable $X$ is continuous, and in this case derive $E(X)$.

**Solution**

1. $F(x)$ is the distribution function of a random variable $X$ for $0 \leq c \leq 1$.
2. For $c=1$ the random variable $X$ is continuous and in this case it results $f(x) = 2(x-1)$ for $1 \leq x < 2$ so it results in
   $$ E(X) = \int_{1}^{2} 2x(x-1) \, \mathrm{d}x = 2 \left[ \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{1}^{2} = \frac{5}{3} $$

What is the proper way to solve this exercise?
I tried by using

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1, $$

but it leads me to a single value of $c=3$, which is not the case of the solution. Is there any formula I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Recall that $F$ is a distribution function (a.k.a. c.d.f.) if and only if the following properties hold:

   > - $F$ is non-decreasing,
   > - $F(x) \in [0, 1]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
   > - $F$ is right-continuous.

   The $F$ defined as in the problem is always right-continuous, so the last property is not our concern. For the rest, a moment of thought tells that we must have $0 \leq \lim_{x\to 2^-} F(x) \leq 1$, which is equivalent to $0 \leq c \leq 1$.

   $\hspace{2em}$ [image: Comparison for different values of c]
2. $X$ is continuous if and only if $F$ is *absolutely continuous*, which means that

   $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

   for some non-negative function $f$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. A necessary condition is that $F$ itself is continuous. (And practically, this is also a sufficient condition at the level of preliminary probability course, as one never deals with singular distribution at this level.)

   Now, we see that $c = 1$ is the only choice for which $F$ is continuous. And with this choice, we easily identify the p.d.f. $f$ as

   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 2(x-1), & 1 < x < 2 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}. $$

   Plugging this to the formula $E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ gives the desired answer.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Continuous_random_variable) it is enough if $F$ is continuous.

Comment: @drhab, Perhaps there are different conventions for what it means to be a continuous distribution. But in most literature that I have checked, the definition of continuous distribution does not encompass singular distributions. (See [this MIT open course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading5b.pdf), for instance.)

Comment: Could you please explain further how do you conclude  that c=1 is the only choice for which F is continuous?

Comment: @1Z10, Plotting the graph of $F$ will be convincing enough. But if one needs a solid proof, notice that $x = 2$ is the only possible discontinuity of $F$. Since $F(2) = 1= \lim_{x\to 2^+}F(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to2^-}F(x) = c$, it suffices to show that they match. So we obtain the necessary condition $c = 1$.

Comment: Clear, thanks @SangchulLee

Comment: @1Z10, Glad it helped. I also added plots of $F$ for different values of $c$. :)

Answer (score 1):

By solving this the PDF should be left out.

The question is about a CDF which is a function with special properties.

In 1) it is asked: for what $c$ does this function indeed have these properties?

In 2) it must be noted that a random variable is continuous iff its CDF is continuous.

So actually it is asked: for what $c$ found in 1) is the function continuous?